# How to send media from server to android app?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an Android app. I want to send images and videos from my server to my Android app. GCM allows only 4kb of data to be sent, but media files are generally of larger size so how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually wrote two blogs posts on this. The [first](http://blog.andromo.com/2012/tutorial-using-airbop-to-push-images-for-bigpicturestyle-notifications/) one shows how to send a link in the payload and then download the files using the URL.

The [second](http://blog.andromo.com/2012/tutorial-using-airbop-to-send-images-in-the-message-payload/) shows how to send small images as part of the 4K payload.

Comment: Thanks selsine , but is there any way i can send media files directly without any download link, file size being greater than max payload size, through cloud or something..

Comment: You can't send data larger than 4K through the payload. Anything that you send through the cloud would be the same as sending a link and then using code to download it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't send it over to your client using gcm. You use gcm to inform the client about new stuff to fetch from your server / the cloud.

Read the [gcm-docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and the "[send-to-sync](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#s2s)" idea under advanced topics.

Check the Google IO web-api video (~ minute 30) for the big picture [Google I/O 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dylFNrvZ_3U) and the files in `android-sdk/extras/google/gcm/samples`

Answer (score 1):

Store the media (images, video etc.) on your server & send link of them through GCM to android app.

Comment: Also i wanted to download these media files and store it locally in app folder for future access , how to do this?

Comment: download & store it to your sdcard or application cache directory