# Upstream Files Using Google Cloud Messaging Cloud Connection server(XMPP)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Real time Chat using GCM Cloud connection server.
I have read the docs [Upstream messages Using GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#upstream).I learnt how to upstream message to my server via GCM.It is more reliable as we all know and better than sending messages to webserver via http.

But now i also want to upload files in chat.but the problem is GCM only allows to upstream maximum of 4KB message.I can use webservices or FTP to upload files to server and then pass the file name to server via GCM.but i want more appropriate solution.So is there any Way to do this via GCM cloud connection server.??

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967479/how-to-send-media-from-server-to-android-app

Comment: you have to create your own server ad leave gcm if you sant to develope chat application like whatsAPP..Because GCM allows only 4kb

Comment: @Nirav Tukadiya...I am in mid-way of implementing CCS in my app. I set the up the server. I am using code in android however I am bit confused about the flow.Question 1:- Is upstream message to server possible without the server downstream message to device first?
Question 2:-How the process starts, what should I do when I get the device id, should I send this to my server as I was doing in normal GCM through HTTP Post or is there any other way?
Question 3:- How do message get identified like if I have 50 users then how do device identify whether the particular message is from particular user?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I'm using on this cases is:

1 - Use [loopj library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to send via POST the file to my server (php p.ex)

```
// loopj supports Http Auth, cookies, params, multipart files, etc. So is a good solution. Like:

...     
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("aaa:bbb".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("cmd", "upp");
params.put("uid", Long.toString(getUser().getId()));
params.put("tid", Long.toString(getUser().getIdTeam()));
try{
  params.put("avatar", file); // File object
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  ...
}

SharePhotoHandler handler=new SharePhotoHandler(mContext,file,notificate);
client.post(URI_BASE, params, handler);
...
```

And I use a custom handler to control the file upload (SharePhotoHandler.class) where the app can control

- onSuccess
- onFailure
- onFinish
- ...

This methods must let you control the upload/download file state (ok, error, uploading, downloading, etc.)

After the file upload, the server must notificate to the other clients that there are a new file to download or on your "onSuccess" method send a GCM message to the other clients. In my case, the server sends to the other clients the filename (+URL) for download it.

Comment: Hello buddy.As i have already mentioned in the question that i do not want to use webservices or FTP to upload files to server.I want to upload files to my server via GCM Cloud connection server.can u suggest me something to do that? Thanks.

Comment: So, another solution is use https://code.google.com/p/p2p-communication-framework-for-android/ . I never tried but its only over BT like the P2PWifi connection.

I didn't know any other solution for your case :( (and a XMPP server used to send files over the stanzas its incorrect, and also you need keep a server)

Answer (score 0):

you've asked:

> So is there any Way to do this via GCM cloud connection server.??

And the answer for files with greater size than ~4k is - no!

Explanation:
GCM mechanism consists lots of servers and bandwidth that costs Google lots of money. Despite it, Google has provided this world-wide service free of charge in order to encourage developers and users to use Android, by allowing them to get a more efficient experience.

Google knew that installing 10+ apps, while each one had to open a connection to a different server in order to get its updates, will slow down the device and will consume expensive bandwidth. So they've implemented the solution of GCM, and that way each device has only one service (Google's) that is constantly searching for updates (instead of many).

Because its a free service, Google had minimized the service to 4k of data. This is good enough because the app will get informed that an update awaits and can then connect to its company's servers to get those updates (instead of constantly searching for them).